# How to get Crossbar.io host name?

Tags: python-3.x, wamp, autobahn, crossbar

I write chat using crossbar.io. We have several nodes of chat.
I need write statistics about each of nodes, that's why I need to get host name where specific node is run.

Is it possible get host name from component instance?

I use last version of crossbar/autobahn and python 3.4.

Expect get - 127.0.0.1 if I use local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the socket library:

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
```

Comment: @AleksandrYarushevsky What do you mean by "wrong hostname" ?

Comment: Now I run on localhost and I got 172.17.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In case of your machine has a resolvable hostname try with:

`import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())`

**Update**. This is a more complete solution, should work fine with all OS:

`import socket

print [l for l in ([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(
socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith('127.')][:1], [[(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()
) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]])
if l][0][0]`

Comment: The same result got 172.17.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1